# How can the cursor location bar graphic in, eg Gedit, be made wider than one pixel?

Tags: themes, gedit, cursor

This question was asked before but not answered correctly, as the answer unhelpfully said to use overwrite mode to get a bigger cursor.  Is there not a way to adjust the cursor in insert mode to something wider?

When editing large text files in Gedit it's very easy to lose the 1-pixel wide position cursor (not mouse cursor), particularly on large high-resolution monitors and using syntax highlighting (theme Kate).

Earlier ask:
[How can I change the Gedit keyboard cursor / caret to a block instead of a bar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538307/how-can-i-change-the-gedit-keyboard-cursor-caret-to-a-block-instead-of-a-bar)